# Implementing std::sort Properly

Tags: c++

I'm attempting to measure the number of compares a variety of search algorithms use.
My code is rather simple -- given a vector of objects, I then call 
`std::sort(students.begin(), students.end());`

I have implemented a compare operator in my `Student` class like so:

```
bool Student::operator < (Student s) const {
    compareCount++;
    return number < s.getNumber();
}
```

where `compareCount` is a static variable. However, my results are puzzling.

[image]

Why would `std::sort` require two compares for a two-element list? This makes me think that some part of my code is incorrect.

Comment: It's not very clear what makes you confused with the results.

Comment: Please use much larger size for experiments. For example, 10000, 100000 or 1000000. 8 is way too small.

Comment: It really depends on what  your input are and how large the input size is

Comment: @lisyarus I'm not sure why std::sort would need two compares on a 2-element list. Isn't it supposed to be more efficient than insertion and selection sort?

Comment: @JaredNielsen: the fact that it used two comparisons on a two-element array does not mean that it is inefficient in the whole. The number of comparisons depends on a particular `std::sort` implementation.

Comment: @JaredNielsen, efficiency is not calculated using small numbers.

Answer (score 1):

"Why would std::sort require two compares for a two-element list?" - Was this done in "debug" mode? I tested this with Visual Studio 2005 - which uses insertion sort for small arrays (size < 32, otherwise it uses quick sort or heap sort). In "release" mode, it does one compare. In debug mode, it checks the caller supplied compare routine to make sure it's < versus <= , so there are two calls made:

```
{   // test if _Pred(_Left, _Right) and _Pred is strict weak ordering
if (!_Pred(_Left, _Right))
    return (false);
else if (_Pred(_Right, _Left))
    _DEBUG_ERROR2("invalid operator<", _Where, _Line);
return (true);
}
```